# Serialize in django witha query set that contains defer

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

i have i little problem, and that is how can serialize a django query with defer ? 
I have this model :

```
class Evento(models.Model):
    nome=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descricao=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    data_inicio= models.DateTimeField()
    data_fim= models.DateTimeField()
    preco=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    consumiveis= models.CharField(max_length=5)
    dress_code= models.CharField(max_length=6)
    guest_list=models.CharField(max_length=15)

    local = models.ForeignKey(Local)
    user= models.ManyToManyField(User,null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode('%s %s'%(self.nome,self.descricao))
```

my query is this :

```
eventos_totais = Evento.objects.defer("user").filter(data_inicio__gte=default_inicio,
                                data_fim__lte=default_fim)
```

it works fine i think (how can i check if the query has realy defer the field user ? ) but when i do:

```
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
eventos_totais = json_serializer.serialize(eventos_totais,
                                           ensure_ascii=False,
                                           use_natural_keys=True)
```

it always folow the natural keys for user and local, i need natural keys for this query because of the fields local. But i do not need the field user.

Comment: So, i have got one solution, and i think it fit's 
doing : eventos_totais = Evento.objects.defer("user").filter(data_inicio__gte=default_inicio,data_fim__lte=default_fim) and them the serializer : eventos_totais = json_serializer.serialize(eventos_totais, fields=('nome','descricao','data_inicio','data_fim','preco','consumiveis','dress_code','guest_list','local'), ensure_ascii=False,use_natural_keys=True) 

if anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To serialize a subset of your models fields, you need to specify the *fields* argument to the serializers.serialize()

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('xml', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('name','size'))
```

Ref: [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields)